# How to Base64 decode and Zlib decompress a string with AutoHotKey

Tags: base64, autohotkey, zlib

The goal is to return the following data:

```
8710861994593;3017620422003;8710624971731;8710624971731;8710861990038;8722700026396;8710861992872;8722700462958;8710449919444;8710449917723;7613031794331;7613031526406;5011546498386;8718114892405;5410013118305;8713300045665;5410013118305;8713300046341;8713300046341;8713300046341;8713300046341;8713300046341;8713300041865;8712000032920;8712000032920;8712800034919;8710624865986;8712800006961;8713300046341;
```

The data above with Zlib compression looks like this:

```
x\x9C\xED\xD1Ar\xC50\b\x03\xD0+!\x901\x8C\xEF\x7F\xAFR\xFF\xFE\xF9\x9Bt\xD5Ug\xB4T\x14\x87\x98W\eV\x89n\xAE\x8E\x13\x86\x9Dnt7\x8BS\xD3\xA5\xB37v\xE0!\xDDs\xF3bMr\xDFf\xE6\x19\x9D\x9F\xCE\xE7\xF9\xBBcz\xAF\xBA\x1D\xD9\x8D&\xF9I{{\x9C\x9D\b\v\xECf\xCC\x84\x9F\xB4<iy\x96\x01\x8B\xC9\xAE\xA8;\xA1\x00V;m\x9DE\x98!\x80\x8AI\xD3E\xCC\xBFpe\xFE\xDAe\x10\x7FO\xA8\xBC\xDF\x9Cm\xCD\x1A\xBC\xDD\x1ER}'\xCE\x85\xDF\e\x9CC\xFD\xBA\xC3\xED,;\x1F&HE*R\x91\x8AT\xA4\"\x15\xA9HE*R\x91\x8AT\xA4\"\x15\xA9HE*R\x91\x8AT\xA4\"\x15\xA9HE*\xFF\\\xE5\v\x8AG\xD5\x1A
```

And Base64 encoding of the Zlib compressed data looks like this:

```
eJzt0UFyxTAIA9ArIZAxjO9/r1L//vmbdNVVZ7RUFIeYVxtWiW6ujhOGnW50
N4tT06WzN3bgId1z82JNct9m5hmdn87n+btjeq+6HdmNJvlJe3ucnQgL7GbM
hJ+0PGl5lgGLya6oO6EAVjttnUWYIYCKSdNFzL9wZf7aZRB/T6i835xtzRq8
3R5SfSfOhd8bnEP9usPtLDsfJkhFKlKRilSkIhWpSEUqUpGKVKQiFalIRSpS
kYpUpCIVqUhFKv9c5QuKR9Ua
```

I want my AHK script to Base64 decode and then Zlib decompress. I've got Base64 decode to work but can't seem to get the Zlib decompression to work.

This is what I'm trying:

```
; Step 2: Zlib decompress the string
; NOT WORKING
len := stringBase64Decoded.length
stringZlibDecompressed := zlib_Decompress(Inflated,stringBase64Decoded,r,len)
MsgBox, %stringZlibDecompressed%
```

When I run this I get a messagebox with a 0 inside.

What can I try to get this to work?

Here's my full code:

```
; ======================================
; ===[ Zlib Functions ]=================
; ======================================

zlib_Decompress(Byref Decompressed, Byref CompressedData, DataLen, OriginalSize = -1) {
  OriginalSize := (OriginalSize > 0) ? OriginalSize : DataLen*10 ;should be large enough for most cases
  VarSetCapacity(Decompressed,OriginalSize)
  ErrorLevel := DllCall("zlib1\uncompress", "Ptr", &Decompressed, "UIntP", OriginalSize, "Ptr", &CompressedData, "UInt", DataLen)
  return ErrorLevel ? 0 : OriginalSize
}

; ======================================
; ===[ Base64 Functions ]===============
; ======================================

StringCaseSense On
Chars = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/

Base64(string)
{
   Loop Parse, string
   {
      If Mod(A_Index,3) = 1
         buffer := Asc(A_LoopField) << 16
      Else If Mod(A_Index,3) = 2
         buffer += Asc(A_LoopField) << 8
      Else {
         buffer += Asc(A_LoopField)
         out := out . Code(buffer>>18) . Code(buffer>>12) . Code(buffer>>6) . Code(buffer)
      }
   }
   If Mod(StrLen(string),3) = 0
      Return out
   If Mod(StrLen(string),3) = 1
      Return out . Code(buffer>>18) . Code(buffer>>12) "=="
   Return out . Code(buffer>>18) . Code(buffer>>12) . Code(buffer>>6) "="
}

InvBase64(code)
{
   StringReplace code, code, =,,All
   Loop Parse, code
   {
      If Mod(A_Index,4) = 1
         buffer := DeCode(A_LoopField) << 18
      Else If Mod(A_Index,4) = 2
         buffer += DeCode(A_LoopField) << 12
      Else If Mod(A_Index,4) = 3
         buffer += DeCode(A_LoopField) << 6
      Else {
         buffer += DeCode(A_LoopField)
         out := out . Chr(buffer>>16) . Chr(255 & buffer>>8) . Chr(255 & buffer)
      }
   }
   If Mod(StrLen(code),4) = 0
      Return out
   If Mod(StrLen(code),4) = 2
      Return out . Chr(buffer>>16)
   Return out . Chr(buffer>>16) . Chr(255 & buffer>>8)
}

Code(i)     ; <== Chars[i & 63], 0-base index
{
   Global Chars
   StringMid i, Chars, (i&63)+1, 1
   Return i
}

DeCode(c)   ; c = a char in Chars ==> position [0,63]
{
   Global Chars
   Return InStr(Chars,c,1) - 1
}

; ======================================
; ===[ Decode & Decompress ]============
; ======================================

; Store the string in a variable
stringToDecodeAndDecompress =
( Join
eJzt0UFyxTAIA9ArIZAxjO9/r1L//vmbdNVVZ7RUFIeYVxtWiW6ujhOGnW50
N4tT06WzN3bgId1z82JNct9m5hmdn87n+btjeq+6HdmNJvlJe3ucnQgL7GbM
hJ+0PGl5lgGLya6oO6EAVjttnUWYIYCKSdNFzL9wZf7aZRB/T6i835xtzRq8
3R5SfSfOhd8bnEP9usPtLDsfJkhFKlKRilSkIhWpSEUqUpGKVKQiFalIRSpS
kYpUpCIVqUhFKv9c5QuKR9Ua
)

; Step 0: Show the full string
MsgBox, %stringToDecodeAndDecompress%

; Step 1: Base64 decode the string
stringBase64Decoded := InvBase64(stringToDecodeAndDecompress)
MsgBox, %stringBase64Decoded%

; Step 2: Zlib decompress the string
; NOT WORKING
len := stringBase64Decoded.length
stringZlibDecompressed := zlib_Decompress(Inflated,stringBase64Decoded,r,len)
MsgBox, %stringZlibDecompressed%
```

Comment: Can't help with "autohotkey", but I verified that the base64 data when decoded is a valid zlib stream. So the data is not the problem.

Comment: Is your decompressed data stored in the "`Inflated`" variable?  The function seems to imply that that first value, "`Byref Decompressed`", is for the decompressed data.  Did you check there?  `MsgBox, %Inflated%`